# Hollow stone columns provide more support?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, stress-strain

In history class in elementary school I remember learning that the Greeks would build their stone columns hollow because they thought this provided more support. Is it true that a hollow column is stronger? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on whether you have a fixed volume of material or a fixed external dimension of the column.

Answer (score 1):

Hollow columns are stronger with respect to buckling (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling ).